# Aside from reading instance variable, what other purposes does attr_reader serve in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following code snippet:

```
class Modi
  include Comparable

  MEDAL_VALS = {"Gold" => 3, "Silver"=> 2, "Bronze" => 1}

  #commenting out attr_reader below breaks the code
  attr_reader :type

  def initialize(type)
    @type = type
  end

  def <=>(other)
    MEDAL_VALS[type] <=> MEDAL_VALS[other.type]
  end
end
```

My understanding is that `attr_reader` is a simply quick tool to print out instance variables for inspection/dev purposes.

When I comment out `attr_reader :type` and leaving `def <=>(other)` as it is, I get:

```
modi.rb:15:in `<=>': undefined local variable or method `type' for # 
<Modi:0x005609e878be80 @type="Bronze", @weight=5> (NameError)
Did you mean?  @type
    from modi.rb:29:in `<'
    from modi.rb:29:in `<main>'`
```

altering `def <=>(other)` to `MODAL_VALS[@type] < MEDAL_VALS[other.type]` (when attr_reader is commented out) leads to this error:

```
modi.rb:15:in `<=>': undefined method `type' for # 
<Modi:0x0055e62ce2feb0 @type="Silver", @weight=10> (NoMethodError)
    from modi.rb:29:in `<'
    from modi.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

Why is a getter, `attr_reader :type`, necessary in this case? (@type should work.. or even self.type - first time encountering this problem of calling an instance variable in another method of the same class)

Please explain.

Comment: "breaks the code" how?

Comment: All three versions of the code work fine for me. You can use `@type` or `self.type`.  So what is your question?

Comment: Incidentally however, you have over-complicated that `<=>` method. You could have just defined it as: `MEDAL_VALS[type] <=> MEDAL_VALS[other.type]`

Comment: Also, `attr_reader` is not only for dev/debugging. As you said yourself, it defines a getter method. This allows you to access the variable via a public instance method. This can be beneficial for many reasons.

Comment: Tom’s right; the getter makes a private instance variable public, allowing it to be accessed from other instances, and from other classes.

Comment: @emaillenin I added the error msgs.

Comment: @TomLord updated code, but the errors persist. Unclear how "all three versions work fine" for you.

Comment: Ohh wait, I see how. "#commenting out attr_reader below breaks the code" ... Well, yes! Don't comment it out then! :D You've already answered your own question in the very first paragraph: "`attr_reader :foo` is a shorthand for `def foo; ...`" ... If you don't define the getter method then `foo`, or equivalently `self.foo`, are not defined. So attempting this will error.

Comment: @TomLord I define foo as an @var in `initialize`.  I don't call `p bar.foo` in code. So Why does `def <=>(other)` depend on `attr_reader :type`?  In other words, I'd understand the purpose of `attr_reader` were I calling foo at some point...I am not.

Comment: @foo You are calling `other.type` in the definition of `<=>`.

Comment: `other.type` won't work if the other instance does not respond to `type`, which it does not unless it has `def type ... `  or `attr_reader :type`. I think `MEDAL_VALS[@type] < MEDAL_VALS[other.instance_variable_get(:@type)]` would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `attr_reader` as a shortcut for creating a method that returns an instance variable name of the same name as the symbol.

You have at least 3 options:

- Use `attr_reader :type` coupled with your `@type = type` assignment
- Create your own `def type; @type; end` method
- Modify your code to use `@type` and `instance_variable_get`:

`if MEDAL_VALS[@type] < MEDAL_VALS[other.instance_variable_get('@type')]`

`attr_reader` is not used (primarily) for debugging/inspection however. It's used to reduce boilerplate code.

Also, `@type` does work, for the current instance. You'll need to call `@type` with `instance_variable_get` per my last example to get the ivar from `other`.

Adding a public accessor method, either via `attr_reader :type` or a `def type` method adds clarity to the intent of the class (e.g. this ivar is meant to be accessed)

References:

- https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader